# How to center menu items ina androidstudio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, navigationview

I made a menu with a navigationView on Android Studio and I put a menu inside with two groups and items. I want to center all the items but it didn't work. Can you help me please?
Here the code
Activity mains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   tools:openDrawer="start">

   <include
       layout="@layout/landing_page"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/nav_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="@color/grey_middle"
       app:itemTextColor="@color/menu"
       app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the activity_main_drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_normal"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_normal"
            android:visible="false" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_avance"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_avance" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_hot"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_hot"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_premium"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_premium" />

    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_stat"
            android:title="@string/menu_stat" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_trophees"
            android:title="@string/menu_trophees" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_langues"
            android:title="@string/menu_langues" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_noter"
            android:title="@string/menu_noter" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
            android:title="@string/menu_contact"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Thanks, everyone, I hope you will succeed to help me.

Comment: Have you tried changing this `android:layout_gravity="start"` to  `android:layout_gravity="center"`?

Comment: yes, but my drawer is strange.
With "start" the menu is on the left of the screen, with "center" it is on the right but outside the screen, and when I click on the image to go to the menu my app crash except if I write "start"